# gutter size for reactstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am trying to use reactstrap to create a layout of 3 columns, with a defined gutter size of 61px, where each of the columns should fill up the container. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correct, then in Bootstrap you should just override `$grid-gutter-width` variable with needed value.

Code for 3 columns will look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    1 of 3
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    2 of 3
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    3 of 3
  </div>
```

In React it would be like this:

```
<Row>
  <Col>.col</Col>
  <Col>.col</Col>
  <Col>.col</Col>
</Row>
```

More about layout - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works

Comment: In reactstrap, when I add <Col> then all 3 of them, take up the full space but don't leave any gutter. I want to be able to specify the size of the gutter as well.

Comment: did you rebuild bootstrap css from sass after changing `$grid-gutter-width` value?

Comment: I am not sure how to change the grid-gutter-width value, when I add it to the scss file it's not working.

Comment: All bootstrap variables are declared with `!default` flag. It means that you can just override the value. After that you have to rebuild Bootstrap as described here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/build-tools/